# Javascript - check if method prototype has been changed?

Tags: javascript, prototype, methods

What's the best method to check if the protoype of a method has been changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "changed" if you mean changed between when your code gets loaded and some later time, you can just store a reference to the function, a la

```
var oldFunc = SomeType.prototype.someFunction;
...
if (oldFunc === someInstance.someFunction) // unchanged, note the use of strict equality
```

But if you mean changed from the default native implementation there's no real way to tell.

Comment: So some libraries like Prototype modify the core object prototypes, like Array.prototype.push or pop. So I'm wondering how you can check if the default prototype method for a native object has been changed.

Comment: @Geuis did you ever figure out a way to check if the default prototype method for a native object has been changed?

Comment: @Stiofán I hope you realize that question was from over *12* years ago. I have no idea what the context was when I asked that originally. Today we have the constructor pattern with getter and setters. You might be able to do something with those.