# How to keep track of how many arrays are created in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, ecmascript-6, benchmarking

I want to be able to keep track of how many arrays a certain program uses, so that I can figure out if unnecessary memory has been allocated.The problem I am running into is Javascript's construct that array literal `[]` does not trigger `Array#constructor`. Is there another way for me to keep track of array usage? ES5 and/or ES6 and beyond.

```
var arrayConstructor = Array // store reference
window.arrCount = 0
window.Array = function() {
  arrCount++;
  return new Array();
}

var arr1 = new Array
window.arrCount // 1

var arr2 = []
window.arrCount // 1 : NOT WORKING!
```

Comment: Can you intercept calls to `Array.__proto__.constructor` or `Object.__proto__.constructor`?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann no, i believe the problem is that javascript short circuits the Array constructor when using literals.

Comment: no you cannot override an array literal, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084889/overriding-array-literal-in-javascript

Comment: Also, X/Y question. You're really asking "How can I profile Javascript code?"

Comment: @DavidEhrmann my apologies, I am trying to figure out this one thing that other languages can easily handle and I was just curious that javascript, whilst improved with many awesome features, can provide a native hook to allow internal analysis to be conducted.

Comment: "...other languages can easily handle." Not C or Java, at least not without a profiler. Being able to intercept constructors like that is *almost* [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Comment: FYI, `window.Array = ...;` simply overrides the value of the global variable `Array`, it doesn't change the functionality of the `Array` constructor. The JavaScript engine already has a reference to the Array constructor, it doesn't need to look it up in the global scope.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann the languages you are refering are compile languages, at runtime they became machine code and thus profiling construct usage is understandably unfeaasable, javascript however is a dynamic language, and that is why I want to say it should easily tailor this need.

Comment: @user2167582 Java doesn't necessarily become machine code. You're also mixing up interpreted vs compiled and static vs dynamic typing. For your problem, it's really just a matter of what hooks are exposed. Different languages have different hooks for profiling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nearly every web browser has a javascript profiler. The purpose of a profiler is to keep track of memory usage, frame rendering speeds, CPU usage, etc.

- Open the Chrome Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
- Click the "Timeline" tab
- Make sure "Memory" is checked in the bar named "Capture"
- Press the record button in the top left
- Refresh the page
- Stop recording once the page has loaded
- Look at the "JS Heap" graph for a breakdown on where your memory went

For example, Chrome's memory profiler looks like this when recording the loading of the Stack Overflow's Top Questions page.

[image]