# How would you get original native function prototype back once changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

“Let’s say I’ve taken a native function prototype—like  `Array.prototype.slice` or
`Array.prototype.indexOf` and assigned it a new value. How would you get the original value back?” 
 
Explanation : I am building third party `JS` widget which embeds small `HTML` to consumers website. We have decided not to use `IFRAME` so `JS` library directly integrated into consumers page. Widgets working fine in test environment but its breaks on some real production website. During the investigation I found, some of the native function not working as expected on those websites which I am using.

- How to investigate that does something wrong with native functions so that I can restore some functions as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990187/create-a-reset-of-javascript-array-prototype-when-array-prototype-has-been-modif)
- Any better approach for third party widget development to avoid such issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a reset of javascript Array prototype when Array.prototype has been modified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990187/create-a-reset-of-javascript-array-prototype-when-array-prototype-has-been-modif)

Comment: It's not good practice overriding those functions!!!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir We can't control execution environment for third party library

Comment: The `prototype` property of global constructor functions is read only (that's the prototype object, not methods set on it). Saving the values of native methods before the other library loads (or copy from an iframe) and use `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply` to use them within your code could be a possibility. But what an ineffable mess created by the 3rd party library!

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir Thats right. But its always possible having manipulated functions through Extensions like Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey and specific userscripts, too. They can inject own code with manipulated functions, custom polyfills and so on. There is no guaranty that a buildin function is still an unmodified native function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580431/recovering-built-in-methods-that-have-been-overwritten

Comment: @DipakTelangre "*We can't control execution environment*" - sure, but this is not your fault then. Just document your library requires some standard functions and will not work if they are overwritten. It's on the website who is using your library to fix this, nothing your library could (or should) do about this.