# Tampermonkey console.log doesn't seem to be the same as the one in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

This is what I have so far:

```js
function loadScript(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.onload = function() {
            resolve();
        };
        script.src = url;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
};

loadScript("https://rawgit2.com/icodeforlove/template-colors-web/master/dist-browser/template-colors.js").then(load);

function load() {
    function logThing(pkt) {
        pkt = pkt.join(', ');
        console.log(c`${'['.red.bold}${pkt.green.bold}${']'.red.bold}`);
    };
    logThing(["Test", "thing", "here"]);
}
```

Normally, in dev tools console, it would log like this:
[image]

But with tampermonkey it logs this:
[image]

Why does tampermonkey do this? And how on earth do I fix this?

Also keep in mind, not using console.log looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug in Tampermonkey. As a workaround you can extract the original console.log from a dummy iframe, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990511).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the script using `@require` instead:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         StackOverflow question 66604679
// @version      0.1
// @author       Wolfy
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604679/tampermonkey-console-log-doesnt-seem-to-be-the-same-as-the-one-in-chrome-dev-to
// @require      https://rawgit2.com/icodeforlove/template-colors-web/master/dist-browser/template-colors.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* globals c */

(function() {    
  function logThing(wordsArray) {
    const stringToPrint = wordsArray.join(',');
    console.log(c`${'['.red.bold}${stringToPrint.green.bold}${']'.red.bold}`);
  }
  logThing(['Test', 'thing', 'here']);
})();
```

The reason is that in your script, the `<script>` is added at page context, so it doesn't patch TM's console.